# JavaScript? Multi-layer Pop Up

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get a multi-layer pop up like this one:
[image: JavaScript Pop Up]

What's the name of this functionality? The only possible way to describe it, as I don't know the name of it, was "multi layer pop up". I've seen it in many websites, can I have a tutorial or maybe a snippet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's generally called a Lightbox.

Known good implementations are

- http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2
- http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/
- http://fancybox.net/

and probably more. Choose the one that fits your requirements best. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What's the name of this functionality?

These boxes are usually called "Modals" or "Modal Pop-ups".

AKX referenced a few very good ones.  I personally prefer facebox: https://github.com/defunkt/facebox

Also, the Twitter Boostrap modal is pretty cool looking as well: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: `Modals` are generally separate windows; whereas HTML elements within the window that seem to popout and darken the background behind it is generally referred to as a `lightbox`

Comment: Over the years the definition/understanding may have changed, though back in the day only dialogs and new windows were considered modals, which required an action before proceeding - perhaps elements are now included.  Regardless, you'll find more hits with the fadeouts with "lightbox".  I also want to add that Twitter's Bootstrap is a great front-end framework that is becoming ever more so popular among programmers these days.